# Anyone know the difference of these 2 pictures?

Tags: image, ipad, safari

Firstly, please go to this url: [celebritywallpaperbase](http://www.celebritywallpaperbase.com/category/1920-x-1440/)

picture #1 is Drew Barrymore smile

picture #2 is Debby Ryan

They are both 1920x1400 but Safari on iPad displays picture #1 with 960 x 720, whereas picture #2 is dislpayed with its actual size 1920 x 1440.

I am making a photolib project for iPad & I wish Safari always display my photos with their actual size.

Thanks in advance!

Scott Chu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have different DPI settings -

Drew's has 150 whereas Debby's has the more standard 72.

Comment: I've tried to make a 100x100 Drew's picture but Safari still shows 960x720. Currently, I know if open this picture in Photoshop and save it as another picture. Safari will show actual size of this new picture file. Any clue why?

Comment: I made Drew picture with resolution of 72x72 or 96x96. Safari still shows 960x720.

Comment: Those are dimensions, not resolution. DPI is different. If you're using photoshop or a similar program, there should be an option for resolution; it may be labeled 'depth' or 'pixels/inch'.